# jQuery form validation without a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and am looking to do a simple form validation. So if the value of the specified text field is a blank string, I would like the related div elements to show.

My HTML and jQuery so far are below, any help would be awesome.

```
<form id="frm">
    <p>Please enter your name</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtname" autofocus >
    <span id="msg_name"></span>

    <p>Please enter your surname</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtsurname" > <span id="msg_surname"></span>

    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Submit">
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#frm").submit(function(event) {      
        var vname = $("#txtname").val(),
            vsurname = $("#txtsurname").val();      

        if(vname == "") {           
            $("#msg_name").text("Please fill this out");
            event.preventDefault();         
        } else if (vsurname == "") {                
            $("#msg_surname").text("Please fill this out");
            event.preventDefault();
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use `required` property. which is available in the html5.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this for education purposes and want to learn the jquery syntaxes

Comment: Uh oh, looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: so does this code not work or what? please clarify what you intend to ask?

Comment: jQuery isn't a standard. HTML5 is. If you want education in best web practises I would do as Jai said and use `require` + a jQuery plugin such as http://jqueryvalidation.org. Or better yet, pick a simple model-binding framework like KnockoutJS to practice on.

Comment: I managed to figure it out an updated the code so that TrueBlueAussie could show me his version, I deleted the question and just updated it so he could submit an answer, but thank you, the new code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production using a plugin would be more appropriate, but as a learning exercise here goes:

Firstly, you need to use the `submit` event and not `click`, otherwise the keyboard will bypass your validation and allow submission anyway.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
```

Start with a common class on the validation messages and hide those with a CSS style.

```
.validation{
    display: none;
}
```

Also use a common class on the items you want to validate. The IDs are not needed if you follow a pattern (e.g. `class="validate"`):

```
<input class="validate" type="text" id="txtsurname" />
```

The validation then just consists of looping through each input that requires validation, and checking if they are blank. If so, you show the `next()` `.validation` element with the message and also stop the form submitting (using `e.preventDefault()`):

```
    $('.validate', this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            // Stop the form submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            // Show the assciated message
            $(this).next('.validation').show();
        } else {
            $(this).next('.validation').hide();
        }
    });
```

And here it is all put together:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q8Lce28u/

As @Matt Browne points out, you probably want to ignore white-space in fields, so also trim the results with `$.trim()`.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q8Lce28u/1/

Comment: And if you also want to reject fields that contain only spaces, you can trim the strings like this: $.trim($(this).val()) == ""

Comment: Have you taken a look at the revised code I put in the question? :) Any reasoning why that would be incorrect?

Comment: @Devin Gray: You do not remove the error messages if the fields are *not* blank. You also test either/or and not both for some reason. Why was that? Do you only want the first error message?

Comment: What if I were to add a $("#msg_name").empty(); in my if condition and $("#msg_surname").empty(); in my if else? and then apply focus() to the txtname element

Comment: @Devin Gray: Yes, that will work, but my next question will be: What happens when you add, 2 or 10 or 100 fields... Do you *ever* want to hard-wire elements together like that and keep replicating code? :)

Comment: ahhh like so.. Makes perfect sense. Thank you for the input :)